# Creating an interaction matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone tell me how to generate an interaction matrix from a dataframe as follows?

Input:

```
    cd1 = [True, False, True, False, False]
    cd2 = [False, True, True, False, False]
    cd3 = [True, False, False, True, True]
    df = pd.DataFrame({"cd1":cd1, "cd2": cd2, "cd3": cd3})
```

I want an output that looks like this

```
   cd1 cd2 cd3
cd1 2   1   1
cd2 1   2   0
cd3 1   0   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `df` to `int` type and compute the matrix `dot` product:

```
df.astype(int).T.dot(df)

     cd1  cd2  cd3
cd1    2    1    1
cd2    1    2    0
cd3    1    0    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more option `matmul` from `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.matmul(df.T.astype(int),df.astype(int)),columns=df.columns,index=df.columns)
Out[283]: 
     cd1  cd2  cd3
cd1    2    1    1
cd2    1    2    0
cd3    1    0    3
```